# bllim/laravel4 datatables package - errors after installation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, datatables, composer-php

Installed the bllim/laravel4-datatables-package yesterday and having no end of problems.  I wonder if anyone has experienced the same?

I added to require-dev in composer.json,

```
"bllim/datatables": "dev-master",
```

In git bash I ran the following, all successful:

```
$ composer update
$ php artisan config:publish bllim/datatables
```

It returned - Configuration published for package : bllim/datables

The fun bit came when I added the following to app/config/app.php

```
'providers' => array(
    ...
    'Bllim\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider',
),



'aliases' => array(
    ...
    'Datatables'      => 'Bllim\Datatables\Facade\Datatables',
),
```

This subsequently breaks my site completely returning the error:

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
…/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Translation/­Translator.php8

[image]

Comment: Can you post the complete error message you're getting?

Comment: have updated with image.  Thanks

Comment: Did you do `composer dump` after installing the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the following command after adding a package:

```
composer dump
```

If that doesn't help, try changing the `"minimum-stability"` from `"dev"` to `"stable"` in your `composer.json` file and run `composer update` again.